# how to handle check keyvaluepair of all TYPE of values

Tags: c#, generics

Scenario: 
I have a utility method to perform operations on a keyvaluepair's key. Key will always be int, but the value can be any type of object. I don't need to know what kind of object the value is.
when I try to perform operation assuming all objects being subtype of object, it doesn't work.

```
object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is KeyValuePair<int, object >) //this check doesn't return true
            {
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to use it generalized, or do I have to check conditions for each value type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Type t = value.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();

if (t == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>))
{

}
```

Advise:
You should first check if it a `t.IsGenericType` (look at Jon's post) and check if the value is assigned

Comment: This will blow up if `t` is not a generic type.

Comment: Yep this is only an example, saw yours. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to generalize this. You have an `object` at hand and the only way to use it is to cast it back to its exact type, including the type parameters.

The "other" option is to use reflection, but that will go a lot differently. For example:

```
var t = value.GetType();
if (t.IsGenericType) {
    if (t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>)) {
        // OK, it's some type of KVP
        var args = t.GetGenericArguments();
        if (args[0] == typeof(int)) {
            // The Key type is int
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will blow-up if the `value` == null ;)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: Haha, touche. Anyway, my point was that since the example `Convert` checks for "any" type of KVP, we should not assume that `value` is a KVP.

Comment: nice and complete example, you'll get a +1